# Ошибка с jQuery и заголовком Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ошибка:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://steamcommunity.com/groups/valve. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://site-name.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Я пытаюсь получить информацию с сайта Steam и вывести на своём через `jQuery`:

```js
$('#kek').load('http://steamcommunity.com/groups/valve .membergrid');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="kek"></div>
```

Как обойти эту ошибку?
Слышал про `JSONP`, но без понятия как его применить.

Comment: Переведу: ошибка: сайт не разрешил другим сайтам грузить с него через ajax. Используй php или iframe.

Comment: В спысле, яваскриптом ты с него инфу не получишь никак.

Comment: @Dimava, неверно. Обходов много.

Comment: Ну, простейший способ - зеркалить через php(в смысле,сервер) - на сервера заголовок не действует, только на браузеры. А вот в браузере чистым js не должно получаться.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать такую конструкцию, вместо того что вы используете. И почитайте про crossdomain request.

```
var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest :     XDomainRequest;
var xhr = new XHR();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://steamcommunity.com/groups/valve.membergrid', true);
// (2) загрузка ответа и вставление кнопки под script
xhr.onload = function() {
    this.response;
}
//@todo если что-то пошло не так, нужно сделать ajax на запись error
xhr.onerror = function() {
    //alert( 'Ошибка ' + this.status );
};
//отправка запроса
xhr.send();
```

Comment: И чем эта конструкция ему поможет?